# Performance Web Test + dotTrace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiling, performance-testing, dottrace

I've tried to figure out if there is a way to tell dotTrace to perform a profile analysis based on a performance test project.

Or run this test while dotTrace is monitoring the project (running in a Web Development server).

So far I didn't find any solution to it, but I think that this would be a perfect situation, as many times, when I run a profiling, I use always the same browsing flow.

I'm using dotTrace 5.0 EAP that is supposed to have a command line tool, but I can't find any documentation about it and I don't even know if this could help me.

Anyone has an idea on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Can you detail what you mean when you say "performance test project"?
On another note, unfortunately command-line profiling has been postponed to further releases (hopefully minor releases within the 5.x family).

Comment: VS2010 allows to create Test Projects. 
These projects allows to create performance web tests.
These tests works recording user browsing (urls, posted data, query parameters, etc.).
These urls are then used to run performance tests.

When profiling a web application with dotTrace, most of the times I have to repeat each time the same browsing flow, exactly as I do in my web performance test project, but with the difference that with dotTrace I can't make it automatically.

Comment: I think we've never tested out this scenario but seems that with command-line runner and dotTrace Performance SDK this should be possible. Both are on later stages of development and should be available in 5.x minor updates

Comment: Thank you gorohoroh. I think I could consider this as an answer. If you change you last comment as an answer, I will mark it as such.